# How to match a route with multiple folder structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a url route that will be of the following format:

```
www.example.com/123/Cat1/Sub1/en
```

From the above, it will map to:

```
123 => userId
Example => Category
Text => SubCategory
en => language
```

This is the only format it will be, it won't have more or less # of levels.

How can I create a custom route to match this?

Comment: You mean like www.example.com/{userid}/{category}/{subcategory}/{langcode} or adding the route and how to handle and recover values? Here you have a nice guide to understand routing in mvc http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814

Comment: What is the purpose of this route? What will it show on the page?

Comment: I am just capturing some information via a GET request, then redirecting so there is no view page.